# convert laravel into raw query

Tags: php, sql, laravel, subquery, where-clause

```
$names = DB::table('heroestags')->where('tag', '=', 'int')->lists('name');
$names2 = DB::table('heroestags')->where('tag', '=', 'mid')->lists('name');

$data = Heroes::whereIn('name', $names)->whereIn('name', $names2)->get();
```

can anyone convert

```
Heroes::whereIn('name', $names)->whereIn('name', $names2)->get()
```

into sql query for me ?

**UPDATE :** found the answer already, done it with a simple subquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use getQueryLog

```
dd(DB::getQueryLog());
```

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/database#query-logging

Comment: tried it, but it is quite hard to understand for me

Comment: You can get only last query `$queries = DB::getQueryLog(); dd(end($queries));`